# Sort a list by multiple other lists in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I have multiple lists of the same size and need to sort one of them by all of the other lists. There is no limit to the number of lists that can be passed in and their order matters. In addition, the user may want to sort the lists ascending or descending. For example, someone may wish to sort a list of people by their age descending first, and if their ages are the same, then sort by their first name ascending.

```
List people = List.of("John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Abe Smith")
List ages = List.of(20, 25, 20)
List firstNames = List.of("John", "Jane", "Abe")

sort(people, ages, "desc", firstNames, "asc")

Result: ["Jane Doe", "Abe Smith", "John Doe"]
```

Edit: The user can sort any lists they want by any other lists they want, as long as they are all the same size. It is not just people. That's just one example of the type of data they may want to sort.

Comment: Are you sure that's Java? It looks more like Python to me.

Comment: This looks messy. I would construct a class `Person` with properties `age` and `firstName` and then use a chained `Comparator<Person>`.

However, @azurefrog is right, it looks like Python.

Comment: It is certainly possible if you can make certain assumptions (same size of lists; lists contain comparable elements etc.). Did you attempt to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I can solve this pretty easily sorting one list by just one other list, but it's not really scalable to multiple lists. I was thinking along the lines of @Michael and chaining multiple Comparators, but I was hoping there was a simpler solution or library out there that might help.

Comment: Maybe there is, but I am not aware of a simpler solution. This is easy to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a generic function f(people, list1, desc, list2, asc ....)
- take hashMap object and store, people as key and value list1, list2 and create myComprator class and sort by value.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this, but as the question mentioned, I also needed specific sort directions per list. I stored those in a separate list. I then sort all the items by comparing two items at a time, looping over each item in their sort lists. If the items are the same, then keep going down the list, otherwise return the comparison (multiplied by -1 if sorting descending at that index)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that what approach you have taken will not help you convert to class as People and take all property inside as #Michael mentioned